# Getting vertices of geometry that type is not known?

Tags: geometry, vertices, openlayers

I am using a WFS service that serves Polygon and Multipolygon geometries. But I do not know ehich ones. So I am converting the wfs response to feature.

```
this.http.get(url, { responseType: "text" })
  .subscribe((response) => {
    
    const feature = new GML2().readFeature(response);
    /// get vertices ???
  })
```

How can I get vertices (corner coordinates) of feature geoemtry? We do not know if that is Polygon or Multipolygon.

Comment: call `feature.getGeometry().getType()`